# Need help with iptables and transparent proxy

Tags: iptables, proxy

I have no idea what I'm doing and these ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71429/redirect-all-non-local-traffic-to-a-socks-proxy), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238784/iptables-redirect-to-remote-squid-proxy) ) don't seem to work for me. I need to force http(s) traffic to go through a proxy on my phone  (WLAN 192.168.43.1:1234)

This sort of works:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT  -d 192.168.0.0/16,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.43.1:1234
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.43.1:1234
```

In the log, I can see that the connection is happening and requests do reach the proxy, but the proxy throws error 65 and for some reason mentions refusing the connection to localhost:80. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but, you should try using `nftables` as it's slowly but steadily replacing `iptables`. It's built by the same company and there is also a utility called `iptables-translate` that will help you make the transition smother. You can learn more about it in the [Debian wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/nftables).

Comment: Don't comment unrelated things please. Wanna recommend ```nftables``` -- fine. But supply an answer, if not a direct one, then at least supply an alternative using nftables. Otherwise such comment does nothing to help

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer.  It's simply a piece of information worth mentioning. Comments after all are meant to be "low-profile" additions to the original post.

Comment: Exactly. An addition. In what way mentioning ```nftables``` to a guy who can't figure out ```iptables``` adds anything useful?

Comment: I don't wish to discuss it any longer. If you disagree with the comment, flag it and let a moderator decide whether it should stay or not. Thank you.